# Fourier Transform of a triangle function

Tags: fourier-transform

Good afternoon,
I am having a question regarding the following function :
Let $g(x)$ be :
$$\begin{cases}\pi + \frac{\pi}{2}x \text{ if }  -2 <x < 0\\
\pi - \frac{\pi}{2}x \text{ if } 0 <x < 2\\
0 \text{    otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
From this I understand I am doing the convolution of two box functions that have are between -1 and 1 as the convolution will double the length.
But i am not sure what will be the value of the height of the box function.

I can clearly guess that the Fourier Transform of my function $g(x)$ will be a $sinc(x)^2$ scaled by a constant. But I am unsure how to find it If anyone is willing to help !
Thanks

Comment: Hey, not really, like I understand how to get the result by computing it, but i was wondering if i could guess / have the intuition for the coefficient scaling my sinc

Comment: I think the linked answer goes into that: How high is the tip of the triangle you get by convolving two 1-height rectangles of width 1? What happens when you multiply a constant to change the height? What happens when you change the width of the rectangles?

Comment: (hint: I'm playing at two fundamental properties of the Fourier transform, one has to do with multiplying with scalars, the others with scaling the time axis)

Comment: I think the highest point should be 1) right? Therefore, in my case i need my highest peak to be $\pi$ therefore the box function should have height of $\sqrt{\frac{pi}{2}}$. The area under the convolution result (the triangle) is also equal to the product of the integrals of the two convolved functions. If the box functions have equal width $w$ and height $h$. We can have $w^2 * h^2 = 2 \pi$?

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you figure out the scaling. https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71973/28112 . It has a scale factor for both amplitude and time/frequency in the derivation.

Answer (score 0):

The top of the triangle is reached when both box functions completly overlap in the convolution integral.

So, you are asking what is the height of the box function with width 2 which has an area of $\pi$, are you not?

BTW, the Fourier transform of your $g(x)$ cannot be a function of $x$.

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry yes i did a typo in the Fourier Transform variable. 
Are you sure that the area of the box function is pi? How do we find it
The final answer is $\sqrt{2 \pi} sinc^2(w)$ btw. But i dont see where $\sqrt{2 \pi}$ comes from. I think the tip you gave is getting me closer to the answer but not quiet there yet

Comment: I did not say the height of the box function to be equal to $\pi$. Read my sentence more carefully.

Comment: Sorry i edited my comment

Comment: When both boxes overlap the area of the resulting box is $\pi$. Sorry for my glitch in the response. The height of the overlaping box is the square of the height of each box. Hence, each individual box has got to be $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ in height.